# Copy and delete selected listbox item

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have code that:

1. UserForm1 Listbox 1 populates it's item from Worksheet1
2. UserForm2 contains textboxes and a submit button
3. When I select an item from UserForm1 ListBox1, it copies the values to UserForm2 Textboxes

I want, when I go into UserForm 2 and click the submit button, the row from Worksheet1 moved to Worksheet2

Below is the code within UserForm1 ListBox1

```
Private Sub UserForm1ListBox1_Click()
    With UserForm2
        .TextBox1 = ListBox1.Column(0)
        .TextBox2 = ListBox1.Column(1)
        .TextBox3 = ListBox1.Column(2)
        .TextBox4 = ListBox1.Column(3)
        .TextBox5 = ListBox1.Column(4)
    End With
End Sub
```

Below is the code within UserForm2 submit button. Getting error commented in the code.

```
Private Sub Userform2SubmitButton_Click() 
    Dim i As Long

    For i = UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then

            Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("A" & i + 1). _
            Copy Worksheets("Worksheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0)

            If UserForm1.ListBox1.ListIndex >= 0 Then
            LastRow = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("A" & LastRow).Find(what:=UserForm1.ListBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate   '<------------------error here!
            Worksheets("Worksheet1").Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete

        End If
     End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You are looking for your search item in a single cell and presumably not finding it, hence the error. You can't activate a cell that doesn't exist.

Comment: @SJR thank you. How do I correct this. My worksheet1 does have data in there

Comment: You can add a line to avoid the error, but what confuses me is why you are only looking in a single cell `Range("A" & LastRow)`. Were you meaning to search a larger range?

Comment: @SJR yeah that is what I was hoping for. Is to search the entire worksheet and select the item from the listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines. Have left a few comments/queries in the code as not sure about a few things. Note how to handle the possibility of `Find` not finding anything.

```
Private Sub Userform2SubmitButton_Click()

Dim i As Long, r As Range, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Worksheet1")

For i = UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ws.Range("A" & i + 1).Copy _
              Worksheets("Worksheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'changed offset to 1 so as not to overwrite
        If UserForm1.ListBox1.ListIndex >= 0 Then
            LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'not sure what this is for
            Set r = ws.Cells.Find(what:=UserForm1.ListBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not r Is Nothing Then 'avoid error if nothing found
                r.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code it does delete the row from worksheet1 but nothing is shown in worksheet2

Comment: Nothing I changed has any effect on copying anything. All I did was change the offset.

Comment: hmmm strange that there is nothing showing in sheet2 after selected row in sheet1 is deleted

Comment: The copying is done before the deletion. Is there a stage missing? What exactly should be copied? Step through the code to check what's going on.

Comment: stepping through keeps taking me back to the userform2

Comment: The code should address the error you were getting; anything else would appear to be beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I am getting active method of range class failed on this line Sheets("StockIn").Range("A7:A" & 
         LastRow).Find(what:=stockin.ListBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, 
         LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate

Comment: I've just explained what causes that error and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find out what was missing. All this time is was just

```
Sheets("Worksheet1").Select
```

I have added this to my original code for anyone who wants to use this as well. Thank you SJR for your help as well.

```
Private Sub Userform2SubmitButton_Click() 
    Dim i As Long
    Sheets("Worksheet1").Select
    For i = UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then

            Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("A" & i + 1). _
            Copy Worksheets("Worksheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0)

            If UserForm1.ListBox1.ListIndex >= 0 Then
            LastRow = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("A" & LastRow).Find(what:=UserForm1.ListBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate   '<------------------error here!
            Worksheets("Worksheet1").Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete

        End If
     End If
    Next i
    End Sub
```